# Java 8 filter based on a boolean

Tags: java, java-8

I want to be able to apply a filter based on the boolean passed in.

```
public static List<Integer> multiplyNumbers(List<Integer> input, boolean ignoreEven){

    return input.stream()
    .filter(number -> !(number%2==0))
    .map(number -> number*2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I want to make the filter step based on the ignoreEven flag. If its true, ignore even numbers. How do I go about doing it? I am doing this to avoid code duplication

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a straightforward or condition to me.

```
.filter(number -> !ignoreEven || (number % 2 != 0))
```

Comment: how would this change if I would want a flag that ignores everything other than even numbers on a need basis? e.g. ignoreEverythingBut2

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to check `ignoreEven` for each element, you can define the predicate itself conditionally:

```
.filter(ignoreEven ? (n -> n % 2 != 0) : (n -> true))
```

Comment: Any time a ternary evaluates one condition to a constant, it's always simplified with arithmetic (in this case, an `or`)

Comment: @Rogue That would require checking `ignoreEven` for each element. If you have an alternative (other than JoeC's), please elaborate.

Comment: I think `#filter(n -> true)` would still evaluate the lambda for each stream element, so the speed concern is negligible (would be the same as `#filter(n -> !ignoreEven)` if `ignoreEven` is false, which the above answer would essentially evaluate to because of `||` vs `|`\)

Comment: @Rogue I agree it's not necessarily a major improvement. I just wanted to post an alternative approach. If we're really going for performance, the best solution is probably `Stream<Integer> stream = input.stream(); if (ignoreEven) stream = stream.filter(n -> n % 2 != 0); return stream...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the condition to your `multiply(...)` method and pass it in `filter`  as shown below.

```
multiplyNumbers(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (x) -> x % 2 != 0).forEach(System.out::println);

public static List<Integer> multiplyNumbers(List<Integer> input,    
                                            Predicate<Integer> filterCondition){

     return input.stream()
                        .filter(filterCondition)
                        .map(number -> number*2)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define two additional helper methods and compose them using `or()` method:

```
private static Predicate<Integer> ignoringEven(boolean ignoreEven) {
    return number -> !ignoreEven;
}

private static Predicate<Integer> ignoringOdd() {
    return number -> (number % 2 != 0);
}
```

Final result:

```
return input.stream()
      .filter(ignoringEven(ignoreEven).or(ignoringOdd()))
      .map(number -> number * 2)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the anyMatch method:

```
return swiftTemplateList.stream()
    .map(swiftTemplate -> swiftTemplate.getName())
    .anyMatch(name -> name.equalsIgnoreCase(messageName));
```